# HTTP Request PUT file (image) to Swift RESTful API (Grails)

Tags: swift, api, rest, grails, httprequest

```
// authenticate
def authSite = new HTTPBuilder( 'https://*********.objectstore.eu/' )
authSite.auth.basic '******', '******'

def filestore = new File("C:/*****")
filestore.createNewFile()
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(filestore, "datawhathwat")

//save object
authSite.request(PUT) { req ->
    uri.path = '/images/********.txt' 
    headers.'Content-Type' = 'image/jpg'

    body: "filestore"
}

authSite.shutdown()
```

When using this code, the headers come through, a file is created, but the file is empty.

Here is a link to the API documentation: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html#createOrReplaceObject

Answer (score 0):

In the request body you are passing a string, rather than the contents of the file you are trying to upload. Get the contents of the file into the body this way:

```
authSite.request(PUT) { req ->
    ...
    body: filestore.bytes
}
```